# How do I update Drush to the latest available version?

Tags: drush, 8, acquia-dev-desktop

On my Mac Mini running OS X 10.11, I installed Acquia Dev Desktop 2 which comes with Drush 8.0.0 rc1. I created a local site which uses Drupal 8, and all went fine; the only problem is that for every Drush command I try, I get an error about a wrong placeholder; the error message gets repeated enough times to make the console output scroll up. For example, with `drush status`, I get the following error messages:

> Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !other FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !fields FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !type FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !type FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !type FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !type FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !type FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !type FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !type FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !type FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240
>   Invalid placeholder: !default FormattableMarkup.php:240

The command then executes normally, giving me the following output:

> Drupal version                  :  8.0.0
>    Site URI                        :  http://default
>    Database driver                 :  mysql
>    Database hostname               :  127.0.0.1
>    Database port                   :  33067
>    Database username               :  drupaluser
>    Database name                   :  tero
>    Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
>    Drupal user                     :
>    Default theme                   :  bartik
>    Administration theme            :  seven
>    PHP executable                  :  /Applications/DevDesktop/php5_5/bin/php
>    PHP configuration               :  /Applications/DevDesktop/php5_5/bin/php.ini
>    PHP OS                          :  Darwin
>    Drush script                    :  /Applications/DevDesktop/drush/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
>    Drush version                   :  8.0.0-rc1
>    Drush temp directory            :  /tmp
>    Drush configuration             :  /Applications/DevDesktop/drush/vendor/drush/drush/drushrc.php
>    Drush alias files               :  /Users/kiamlaluno/.acquia/DevDesktop/Drush/Aliases/aliases.drushrc.php
>    Install profile                 :  standard
>    Drupal root                     :  /Users/kiamlaluno/Sites/devdesktop/tero
>    Site path                       :  sites/default
>    File directory path             :  sites/default/files
>    Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
>    Sync config path                :  sites/tero.dd/files/config_05LkLxb13V9Aql8lLTwnzSDjZKUwSM1QqJosn6985ubZ7AvwwnV1j8I6FHt 
>                                       qunj1liphJjAVpw/sync

Still, I would like to avoid these error messages.

How do I update Drush without installing it globally?
I don't want to install it globally because I am using the console Acquia Dev Desktop opens for me, and its Drush takes the precedence over any other command.

Comment: It depends how it was installed - these days it should be as simple as `cd /path/to/drush; git pull; composer install`, or whatever slight variation makes sense

Comment: Acquia Dev Desktop comes with an installer which installs the application, which contains all the files it needs (since a OS X application is essentially a directory containing an executable and other files).

Comment: `ls -al (which drush)` @kiam, that'll tell you where it's executing. `cd` to that folder, then run the other commands. If it's inside an OSX package that's fine, the command line doesn't treat those any differently to a normal folder

Comment: I actually found the answer before asking the question. I asked the question because it was not as immediate as it would seem, and because what I found in a site didn't completely work.

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: Acquia Dev Desktop is terrible to use, I'm usually avoiding this whenever possible.

Comment: Agreed @kenorb, Homebrew makes it so easy to install a proper stack that tools like Acquia Dev Desktop should commit hari kari ASAP and stop confusing people (in my opinion). And if homebrew is too much effort, [it gets even easier](https://puphpet.com/). Still, for those stuck with Acquia, this is an important question I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the commands I have executed from the terminal to update Drush.

```
cd /Applications/DevDesktop/drush
rm -rf vendor/drush/drush
rm -rf vendor/bin/drush*
rm -rf vendor/psy
rm -rf vendor/bin/psysh
composer.phar require drush/drush:8.*
```

I was following [Introducing Drush 8](https://pantheon.io/blog/introducing-drush-8) (Composer Users Downloading Stable Versions of Drush), where the suggested command to update Drush (although globally) is `composer global require drush/drush:8.*`. When I tried the following commands, I got an error message.

```
cd /Applications/DevDesktop/drush
composer.phar require drush/drush:8.*
```

The error message was the following one:

> ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: don't install drush/drush 8.0.1
>       - Removal request for drush/drush == 8.0.0.0-RC1
>       - Installation request for drush/drush 8.* -> satisfiable by drush/drush[8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.0-rc1].
>       - Conclusion: remove psy/psysh v0.5.2
>       - Can only install one of: psy/psysh[v0.6.0, v0.5.2].
>       - Can only install one of: psy/psysh[v0.6.0, v0.5.2].
>       - drush/drush 8.0.0 requires psy/psysh ~0.6 -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.6.0, v0.6.1].
>       - Conclusion: don't install psy/psysh v0.6.1|keep psy/psysh v0.5.2
>       - Installation request for psy/psysh == 0.5.2.0 -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.5.2].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little old question, but in 2018 we still have problems with that. 
First go to the tools folder in the DevDestktop

```
cd /Applications/DevDesktop/tools/
```

You can check in the composer.json file wich version do you have, currently drush 8.1.10..

So, for update to the last stable version run the next command:

```
composer require drush/drush 8.1.15
```

You can check your version, by running `drush --version`